# Open source Linux cluster project

Tags: linux, open-source, cluster-computing

Are there open source Linux cluster project available? Could someone point me to the web link?

Juhani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MOSIX](http://www.mosix.org)

[Beowulf](http://www.beowulf.org/)

[Linux HA](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Main_Page)

Answer (score 3):

Most information you seem to require can be found [here](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Comparison_of_cluster_software).

Comment: If you like it, you could accept my solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's this [Pelican HPC](http://pareto.uab.es/mcreel/PelicanHPC/) livecd, which uses MPI. The livecd approach makes it easy to try out things without breakage.

Oh it also features easy install on networked PCs by booting via PXE over the network.